# How do I update a single data in an array with react native firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My Purpose: When the onPress operation occurs, the followCategory value found in the id I clicked should be false if true, and true if false.Firestore
Update single item in an array field

How can I find the id of the button I clicked?

```
 const dbStore = firebase.firestore();
 export default Kategoriler = () => {

  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  const fireStore = dbStore.collection('Agar').doc('Kategoriler');
  
  function getCategory(){

    fireStore.get().then((docSnapshot)  =>{

      if(docSnapshot.exists){

      
            const data=docSnapshot.data().follow;
            const categoryList=Object.values(data) || [];
            console.log(data);
            setList(categoryList);
      } 
      
    })
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
  
    getCategory();
    
    
    
    },[]);

  
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
               
            <FlatList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style = {styles.cat}
            data = {list} 
            keyExtractor = {item => item.idkey}
            renderItem = {({item,index}) => (
            
              <View style = {styles.catItem}>
             
                <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image source = {{uri: item.image}} style = {styles.loggo}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <View style = {{flexDirection: "column" , 
                    justifyContent: "space-around" , 
                    alignItems: "center"}}>
                        <View>    
                        <Text style = {styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text style = {styles.text}>{item.postCount}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View>
                        <Image style = {{width: 30 , height: 30 , marginTop: 4 }}
                        source = {{uri: 'https://ibb.co/L5WY5X2'}} />
                        </View> 
                        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity 
            
          onPress={
            
              ()=>{
                 fireStore.update({
                    followCategory:!item.followCategory,
                  
                  
                 });
                
              }

            }
              >
              <Icons
              name={item.followCategory ? 'heart' : 'heart-o'}
              size={20}
              color={'#E02401'}
              
              
              />

             
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
            )}
            >
           
            </FlatList>

            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
```

This firestore data, Update single item in an array field

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a bit? Do you want to update a nested array in firestore, or get the id prop of the follow array elements'?

Comment: @Dániel Boros
For example, I want to change the followCategory(boolean) in the index at index 0. So Follow-0.-followcategory , and I want to do this with the help of button

Comment: You cant update the nested array in firestore, you have update the whole `follow` props. I write the example below.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a copy of your array from your database, then update whatever you want to change and upload it again.

Make sure to merge the document, not to replace it by using

`yourDoc.set({follow: newArray}, {marge: true})`

Comment: In which cases should I use realtime database and in which case cloud firestore? Where can I learn?

Comment: You can use the firestore database for everything. It builds on the realtime database, wich is the initial database of firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on `onPress`

```
const followNextState = list.map((item, idx) => {
  if (index === idx) {
    return ({...item, followCategory: true})
  } else return item
})

firestore.update({follow: followNextState})
```

Comment: How can I get index value from flatlist?

Comment: In `renderItem` will you find it.